# Convert android application to library causes errors

Tags: android

I want to create a Pro version of my android app.
After some investigation I think the best way to do that is to make my current application a library and create two applications that reference this lib.

Unfortunately I don't come very far.
My problems start in the first step I do. When I check the "Is library" checkbox in eclipse and perform a project -> clean I get a lot of errors. Unfortunately I don't get an error that tells me what causes the problem. I just get the 233 errors telling me that my “R” cannot be found…

Can anyone help me with that?

UPDATE:

This error comes up in the middle of the build but does not show up when the build is over:

```
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Stefan\Documents\codefarm\time\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar'
```

But this lib is definately existing and it seems not to be a problem when the "Is library" isn't checked...

UPDATE2:
I figured out how I can make this work but still need a better solution. When I check the "Is library" checkbox I can add it to my new application project as library. Now I have to uncheck the "Is library" again so that the project compiles. The project successfully starts but everytime I exit eclipse I have to do these steps again...
Impossible to work this way!

Comment: uncheck the is Library? you still can reference?

Comment: I haven't created another project yet since my problems start in the first step. Unchecking the "Is library" again removes the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I figured out what caused the problem.
Some time ago I switched from the default android context menu to my own but I was to lazy to update my switch/case with new Id’s.

```
case R.id.mi_Delete_Calendar_timerecord: {
```

After I changed that to

```
    private final int mi_Delete_Calendar_timerecord = 1;
```

it was working…
I have no explanation why this is not working when I create a library. I didn't care because I thought that a int is a int and it doesn't matter if I define it or I reuse it from the genreated R (however, I know this is no clean code but I don't understand why it does not compile as library)...